# Is there a formula for $f(x)$ where $f(x)=$ the sum all simplest fractions with the numerator$+$denominator equals $x$

Tags: functions, closed-form, coprime

Is there a closed-form for
$$f(n)=\sum\limits_{\substack{k=1 \\ (k,n)=1}}^{n-1} \frac{k}{n-k}$$
For example, $f(5)=1/4+2/3+3/2+4/1= 6+5/12$; $f(6)=5+1/5$

The list of $f(x)$ from $x=1$ to $x=8$ is:

$(0,1,5/2,10/3,77/12,26/5,223/20,988/105)$

I'm trying to plot this but I would take a while to do it by hand that's why I ask. If there isn't a nice formula could you write a program that plots it I'm not the best at coding.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a simple formula for this it has the stuff to do with prime factorization

Comment: To be clear: for $n$ a positive integer, you're defining something like $$f(n)=\sum\limits_{\substack{k=1 \\ (k,n)=1}}^{n-1} \frac{k}{n-k}$$

Comment: @Integrand okay would you know how to put this in a calculator like wolfram alpha? thanks tho it helps

Comment: Here's a plot up to 100: 


ListPlot[Table[Sum[Boole[GCD[k,n]==1] k/(n-k),{k,1,n-1}],{n,1,100}]]

Comment: Please don't delete posts.  You'd be erasing the work people have put in trying to help you.

Comment: "I'm not the best at coding." You can not check your work properly if you don't have at least a couple of values correctly by hand. $f(6) = 1/5 + 2/4 + 3/3 + 4/2 + 5/1$ if I get your rule correctly. That is not $5 + 1/5$ as you write.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó your wrong 2/4 isn't a simplified fraction so isn't added same with 3/3 and 4/2

Comment: Ah, I see now, sorry. In this case, if there will be no closed formula provided (which is highly likely), then for both programmatical or manual calculations one trivial optimisation is to throw away all even values of $k$ when $n$ is even.